# Accessing an array as a struct vs undefined behavior

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, undefined-behavior

Let's say we have this structure with 4 `float` values and a `float` array with 4 elements.

Is it then undefined behavior or not to access the array as a `Foo` instance and change the array elements through that instance?

```
struct Foo
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;
};

float values[4] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

int main()
{
    auto& floats = *reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(values);
    floats.a = 0.0f;
    floats.b = 0.0f;
    floats.c = 0.0f;
    floats.d = 0.0f;
}
```

Compile and run online: http://cpp.sh/6y7m

Comment: Calling strict aliasing, strict aliasing, we have a call on line 7.

Comment: How can this possibly be well-defined? There could be arbitrary padding between each of your class members.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit right. Wanted that in black and white :)

Comment: As a matter of fact, @LightnessRacesinOrbit is saying something else. Let's say, you replace your arrays of float with array of chars, and start accessing elements of this at a certain offsets and memcopying float values into it. That program would be well-formed and wouldn't have undefined behavior. But you would be unlikely to find the float members in the struct to contain the values you'd expect them to, due to padding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is an undefined behavior indeed. It violates so-called strict aliasing rule - which prohibits access to the object through *unrelated* pointer (I won't dwell into details of what is *unrelated* here, unless specifically asked).

However, an array of floats to a struct is unrelated.

Here is an extract from Standard (3.10 / 10):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
>   undefined:
>
> — the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type similar (as
>   defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type that is
>   the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to
>   a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types
>   among its elements or nonstatic data members (including, recursively,
>   an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained
>   union),
>
> — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of
>   the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a char or unsigned char type.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Or maybe point me to the relevant sections in the standard? Thanks!

Comment: @JohannGerell, my favorite section :) Give me 3 mins.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration on "unrelated" - I had that hunch also.

Comment: @JohannGerell http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing

Comment: @JohannGerell C languahe has [different rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type#Compatible_types) which are more permissive that C++ ones, and many compilers allow to use them in C++ as compiler extention. However aliacing struct and array is not allowed.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, C only differs from C++ in that it allows compatible types (C++ doesn't have a notion of compatible type). However, I would not really call them super permissive.